# How to resolve cors issue in laravel version 10

Tags: laravel

I have upgraded my laravel version from 9 to 10. I have removed fruitcake/cors package while upgrade,so that facing cors issue. Is there any alternate package available to fix this issue.

Comment: Why did you remove fruitcake/CORS package?

Comment: Have you tried basic research and information provided in [laravel 10 migration](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#note-for-users-upgrading-to-laravel-9-10-or-higher)?

Comment: I used  \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class in  kernal.php provided by laravel. This resolved the issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Since Laravel 9.2, this Middleware is included in laravel/framework. You can use the provided middleware, which should be compatible with the Middleware and config provided in this package. See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/5825/files for the changes.
>
> Steps to upgrade:
>
> 1. Remove `"fruitcake/laravel-cors"` from your composer.json
> 2. Replace `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,` with `\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,` in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

From [laravel-cors laravel 10 migration guide](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/blob/master/readme.md)

Comment: Yes, Now working by ```\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,```

Comment: Did this, but getting this error in the browser. `Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Missing Allow Origin)`

Comment: @gihandilanka probably you have missing CORS configuration within settings, without further description, what have you tried and where the problem exactly is, I can't do much.